# Need Help with Date expression - AWK in a csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, date, csv

**Situation:** csv file has date column with different date formats, I want to convert them into a unambiguous date format (like +"%m-%d-%Y").

**Example File data :** File name = Date_Test_new.csv

```
3/29/2019, Test, "I am new to, Unix", 04-05-2023
03/29/19, Test, "I am new to, Unix", 04-5-2023
Apr-29-2019, Test, "I am new to, Unix", "Apr-01-2019"
3/29/2019, Test, "I am new to, Unix", "Apr-01-2019"


**Source Date formats**
DD-MMM-YY -> 08-Sep-23

DD-MMM-YYYY -> 08-Sep-2023

MM/DD/YY -> 09/08/23

MM/DD/YYYY -> 09/08/2023

MM-DD-YYYY -> 09-08-2023

YYYYMMDD -> 20230908

DDMMMYY -> 08Sep23
```

**Desired Output**

```
03-29-2019,Test, "I am new to, Unix", 04-05-2023
03-29-2019, Test, "I am new to, Unix", 04-05-2023
04-29-2019, Test, "I am new to, Unix", 04-01-2019
03-29-2019, Test, "I am new to, Unix", 04-01-2019
```

**What I Tried but is throwing syntax errors:**

```
awk -F ',' '$1="date -d "$1" +"%m-%d-%Y" " ' Date_Test_new.csv > New_Output.csv
```

*In short how to convert the date format of one entire column in a file to Different date format?*

Any help would be a great learning for me . THank you

Comment: awk is not really the right tool for this. awk is awkward to use for actual CSV data; the csv separator is comma not comma+space; awk's datetime functions don't allow parsing arbitrary date formats. What date does `04-05-2023` represent?

Comment: You might want to validate your desired output; eg line 3 you have April becoming "03" and lines 4 and 5 you have 2019 becoming 2023.  Is this really what you want, or a mistake in the question?

Comment: @StephenHarris that was mistake in typing. I had edited the desired output. Could you please help me in any which way with this?

Comment: @glennjackman - MM-DD-YYYY is the desired date out put
Source could be anything like below;  Can you help with any solution outside of awk also?

DD-MMM-YY -> 08-Sep-23

DD-MMM-YYYY -> 08-Sep-2023

MM/DD/YY -> 09/08/23

MM/DD/YYYY -> 09/08/2023

MM-DD-YYYY -> 09-08-2023

YYYYMMDD -> 20230908

DDMMMYY -> 08Sep23

Comment: I wouldn't call MM-DD-YYYY an unambiguous date format. A large part of the world uses DD-MM-YYYY. Have you considered YYYY-MM-DD instead?

Comment: @roaima,

Yeah. I need help fixing the syntax of my code. I am okay with any date type conversion . (YYYYMMDD or DD-MM-YYYY)

Comment: Great. Please [edit] that into your question

Comment: @roaima - I just did. Ty

Comment: The problem could be reduced to more minimal reproducible example. CSV is secondary, what seems to be the real question is how to parse dates in multiple input formats and output them in a single format. Off the top of my head, Perl has [modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Datetime%3A%3AFormat) capable of this.

Comment: You shouldn't be [OK with ANY date type conversion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756355/need-help-with-date-expression-awk-in-a-csv-file/756555#comment1440825_756355) as many such as `DD-MM-YYYY` are ambiguous and/or can't be directly sorted (including compared for greater than or less than). You should require the output to use the unambiguous, directly sortable, easily splittable [ISO 8601 date format](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html), `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Are Perl and/or Raku answers acceptable? Raku has `ISO 8601` date-handling functions built-in (https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your real data is in a valid CSV format, i.e. no blanks after the field-separating commas, then using GNU awk for `FPAT`, `gensub()`, and the 3rg arg to `match()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        mths[tmp[i]] = i
    }
    FPAT = "[^,]*|(\"([^\"]|\"\")*\")"
    OFS = ","
}
{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        val = gensub(/^"|"$/,"","g",$i)

        day = mth = yr = 0
        if ( match(val,/^([0-9]{1,2})-([[:alpha:]]{3})-([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})$/,d) ) {
            # D-MMM-YY or DD-MMM-YY or ...YYYY
            day = d[1]
            mth = mths[d[2]]
            yr  = d[3]
        }
        else if ( match(val,/^([[:alpha:]]{3})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})$/,d) ) {
            # MMM-D-YY or MMM-DD-YY or ...YYYY
            day = d[2]
            mth = mths[d[1]]
            yr  = d[3]
        }
        else if ( match(val,/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})$/,d) ) {
            # M/D/YY or M/DD/YY or MM/D/YY or MM/DD/YY or ...YYYY
            day = d[2]
            mth = d[1]
            yr  = d[3]
        }
        else if ( match(val,/^([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})$/,d) ) {
            # M-D-YY or M-DD-YY or MM-D-YY or MM-DD-YY or ...YYYY
            day = d[2]
            mth = d[1]
            yr  = d[3]
        }
        else if ( match(val,/^([0-9]{2})([[:alpha:]]{3})([0-9]{2})$/,d) ) {
            # DDMMMYY
            day = d[1]
            mth = mths[d[2]]
            yr  = d[1]
        }
        else if ( match(val,/^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/,d) ) {
            # YYYYMMDD
            day = d[3]
            mth = d[2]
            yr  = d[1]
        }

        if ( length(yr) == 2 ) {
            yr = "20" yr
        }

        day += 0
        mth += 0
        yr  += 0

        if ( (1 <= day) && (day <= 31) &&
             (1 <= mth) && (mth <= 12) &&
             (1 <=  yr) && (yr  <= 9999) ) {
            $i = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", yr, mth, day)
        }
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk Date_Test_new.csv
2019-03-29,Test,"I am new to, Unix",2023-04-05
2019-03-29,Test,"I am new to, Unix",2023-04-05
2019-04-29,Test,"I am new to, Unix",2019-04-01
2019-03-29,Test,"I am new to, Unix",2019-04-01
```

I think I covered every date format you listed and more but just add `else if ( match(...) ) { ... }` blocks for any other format you want to be able to parse.

You could also consolidate some of the more similar `match()` calls by loosening some of the regexps or make some regexps more restrictive if that works better for you.

Change `sprintf()` to whatever output format you like but I recommend you stick with the [ISO 8601 date format](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html), `YYYY-MM-DD`, I'm using for ease of working with those dates subsequently.

Feel free to add or change any checks for valid dates if you like. Since we're using GNU awk you could, if you like, remember the input format in each block, then at the bottom use `mktime()` to convert the newly created date to seconds since the epoch, then `strftime()` to convert those seconds back to a date in the original format to see if it's identical to the original date for a foolproof verification that you matched and converted accurately. Left as an exercise ... :-).

If your data really does have blanks after the field-separating `,`s:

```
$ cat file
3/29/2019, Test, "I am new to, Unix", 04-05-2023
03/29/19, Test, "I am new to, Unix", 04-5-2023
Apr-29-2019, Test, "I am new to, Unix", "Apr-01-2019"
3/29/2019, Test, "I am new to, Unix", "Apr-01-2019"
```

you can turn it into a valid CSV with:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/, /,",",$i)} 1' file
3/29/2019,Test,"I am new to, Unix",04-05-2023
03/29/19,Test,"I am new to, Unix",04-5-2023
Apr-29-2019,Test,"I am new to, Unix","Apr-01-2019"
3/29/2019,Test,"I am new to, Unix","Apr-01-2019"
```

All of the above assume your fields cannot contain newlines. If the fields contain newlines it'd take a bit more work. For that and more info on processing CSV with awk see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).